# Howto find interface with specific method?

Tags: java, eclipse

I look for a tool in eclipse to find a interface's method who implements `void detach()`.

I have tried the "Java Search" but only found declarations in real Classes.
[image]
Any suggestions?

Comment: there is no @Override in Interface :)

Comment: @Override and "void detach()" usually go in separate lines, so you won't be able to find anything if you try to search for that specific string right?

Comment: @JosefN i dont know why they vote your comment up. I wrote `implements`!

Answer (score 0):

to find interface : remove `@Override` from search key word

to find implementation: search for interface and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click in eclipse (I assume from the picture you posted)